# How to import minified js file on react create app

Tags: reactjs, import, create-react-app, minify

So I have this Create react app (I don't really understand webpack), and I wanted to use EaselJS on this one, However the NPM counterpart of EselJS is their version 2 (BETA) and is quite unstable and undocumented - That's why I wanted to use the minified version.

I have a `easeljs.min.js` on my project but I don't know how to "import it".

doing `import './easeljs.min.js' seems to also generate a lot of linting issues and  seems to nor work.

EDIT:
I tried using react-helmet and append it as a script tag, but it seems that react is doing something with the minified version and causes it to error. (`unexpected token <`)

Comment: Did you try this `https://www.npmjs.com/package/easeljs` It seems to be version 1.0.2?

Comment: @johnnypeter oh, I didn't saw this, I only saw this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@createjs/easeljs I'll try it now

Comment: @johnnypeter I tried that library and it seems to throw an error `createjs is not defined` :(

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to fix it:

I installed `react-app-rewired` created `config-overrides.js` and added this code:

```
module.exports = function override(config, env) {
  if (!config.resolve || Object.keys(config.resolve).length === 0) {
    config.resolve = {};
  }

  if (!config.module || Object.keys(config.module).length === 0) {
    config.module = {};
  }

  if (!config.module.rules || config.module.rules.length === 0) {
    config.module.rules = [];
  }

  const resolve = {
    alias: {
      createjs: "createjs/builds/1.0.0/createjs.js"
    }
  };

  config.resolve = {
    ...config.resolve,
    ...resolve
  };

  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /node_modules[/\\]createjs/,
    loaders: ["imports-loader?this=>window", "exports-loader?window.createjs"]
  });

  return config;
};
```

It seems that it is an issue with createjs itself https://github.com/CreateJS/Combined/issues/12

I also ended up using this repo for createjs.